# List.Add Method is not working

Tags: c#, sql

```
public class abc
    {
        public abc(int ID, string Date, string jobtype, string command)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.Date = Date;
            this.jobtype = jobtype;
            this.command = command;
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string jobtype { get; set; }
        public string command { get; set; }
    }

    public List<abc> getdata()
    {
        List<abc> data = new List<abc>();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Table]",connection1);
        using (connection1)
        {
            connection1.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    **data.Add(sdr["job_type"]);**
                }
                connection1.Close();
                return data;
            }
        }
    }

   private DataTable Getdata(SqlCommand cmd)

    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connection1;

        try
        {
            connection1.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }

        catch
        {
            return null;
        }

        finally
        {
            connection1.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            connection1.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

My code as above, I got an error on data.Add(sdr["job_type"]); where:

Error   2   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List has some invalid arguments 
Error   3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.abc'

I try to find some solutions through Google but no luck finding one. I quite new to C# so can anyone please tell me where I did wrong? The code are some example that I came across during searching.

Is there any alternative to the ways to place data from database in a list like shown above? Thanks.

Comment: Observe that you are using a typed list. This list should contain an object of type 'abc', however, the Reader, is not returning an object of type 'abc'.

Comment: 1) don't close the connection inside the reader; 2) why you need a constructor when you can do something like `new abc(){ID=your_db_value_casted properly}` when your properties are public? if they were private/protected i could understand but for public ones? 3) use return at the end of the function and just assign the value on the way followed by a `break;`... it's better than an return inside a `using statement`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply cast your database object to your `abc` class. You will need to read each column and create a new `abc` object, as your list can only contain objects `abc`.

For example (I am doing this based on MySQLReader knowledge, it may be a bit different)

```
while (sdr.Read())
{
    data.Add(new abc((int)sdr["ID"],
    (string)sdr["Date"],
    (string)sdr["job_type"],
    (string)sdr["command"]));
}
```

Obviously the column names need to be renamed to your exact column names.

Comment: Updated answer to use `SQLDataReader`, hopefully that is correct, I'm used to using the MySQL extension instead.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to create a new `abc` object from the actual row you are reading from the Database.

Something like

```
data.Add(new abc(
    Convert.ToInt32(sdr["ID"]), 
    Convert.ToString(sdr["DATE"]), 
    Convert.ToString(sdr["job_type"]), 
    Convert.ToString(sdr["command"]))
    );
```

Comment: this can fail! cause you can get a null or a string instead of an int and bye bye code...

Comment: @HellBaby, this is true. You can change this to be a lot more defensive, and do validation checks on the actual values. I would expect the ID to be an autonumber, but would you then rather recommend using a nullable int rather?

Comment: @AdriaanStander double check = less bugs ;)

Answer (score 1):

May be like this

You need to Specify Your Properties with Creating Object of Class

```
data.Add(new abc() {job_type1=sdr["job_type"].ToString()});
```

Or

Passing Data To Constructor Of Your Class `Abc`

```
data.Add(new abc(sdr["job_type"].ToString()));
```

For Reference

[Go through MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
 using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                abc temp = new abc();

                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                     temp = new abc();
                     temp.ID =  Convert.ToInt32(sdr["ID"]);
                      temp.Date =  Convert.ToDate(sdr["Date"]);
                       temp.jobtype =  Convert.ToString(sdr["job_type"]);
                     temp.command =  Convert.ToString(sdr["command"]);
                    data.Add(temp);
                }
                connection1.Close();
                return data;
            }
```

Comment: Why are you converting strings to ints?

Comment: `temp.Date =  Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Date"]);` ??

Comment: @HellBaby  i only want to show how to make object and how to add into list

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to modify the `abc`'s constructor so that it takes the `SqlDataReader` as a parameter and do the assignment work inside the constructor:

```
public class abc
{
    private enum Column
    {
        ID = 1,
        Date = 2,
        jobtype = 3,
        command = 4
    }

    public abc(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        ID = sdr.GetFieldValue<int>[Column.ID];
        Date = sdr.GetFieldValue<string>[Column.Date];
        jobtype = sdr.GetFieldValue<string>[Column.jobtype];
        command = sdr.GetFieldValue<string>[Column.command];

        // or
        //ID = (int)sdr["ID"];
        //Date = (string)sdr["Date"];
        //jobtype =(string)sdr["jobtype"];
        //command = (string)sdr["command"];
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string jobtype { get; set; }
    public string command { get; set; }
}
```

this way your loop is nice and clean and the *parsing/casting* (if any) encapsulated:

```
while (sdr.Read())
{
    data.Add(new abc(sdr));
}
```